# Execute CHECKOUT GIT commad before commit

Tags: git, git-checkout

i had worked in code source for 2 hours; unfortunately, by mistake ( terminal history ) i had execute checkout before commit can i revert it ?

Command revert, reset doent's same working in this case

Comment: I think it's gone for forever :( https://github.blog/2015-06-08-how-to-undo-almost-anything-with-git/

Comment: Unstaged changes aren't tracked by Git, beyond Git recognizing that the local directory has changed relative to the branch head. If those changes are undone, there is no way for Git to retrieve them. You only hope is if you have a recent backup, either made by your editor or by your operating system.

Comment: unfortunately it happened due to lack of concentration, I have no backup. it's a recente code when i have finished i wanted to execute the commit, as I was lazy I used the history of my terminal by selecting the wrong command :/

Comment: Sorry but saying checkout without first saying commit or stash is a classic way to lose your work. The only time I ever do that is when what I’m checking out is a branch I just created.

Comment: @matt  it was stupid from me ! luckily it was on a single file, i had rewrite it after my post here to not forget what i have done (1.5 extra houre) it's work well now :)

Comment: If you only do `git checkout`, your changes are still there. Simply `checkout` your correct branch again.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. Unless you had `git add`ed those changes, they never went into Git.

At this point your best chance is a file recovery utility that can maybe find the edited content of those files. But the odds are slim. You can make your chances better by not adding more writes to that disk which might overwrite the deleted changes. For example, put the recovery software on a different drive.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i think the best for me to avoid wasting more time. is to rewrite the code

I lost a controller class ... I can base myself on the view and model to remember what I have done.

it will teach me to be more careful when I am on a terminal

Comment: @KahinaZiouane That is what I would recommend. You'll write it even better the second time. Now that there's a separate `git restore` command, I looked to see if the "file restore" functionality of `git checkout` could be turned off, but I did not find anything.

Comment: thank you for your help i appreciate that and conforte me to read "You'll write it even better the second time" :)